# Unable to extract Json Value in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I hoping some expert on here will find this easy but I can't seem to get the json values to extract correctly from the below

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @json = '{"test":[{"sId":428659635,"uid":"1110093","rTime":"20180509 05:01:46"}]}';

SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.test.sId');
```

I just seems to get Null, is there something I'm missing cause looking on the net its the same as all the examples I've done

Answer (score 2):

`test` is an array so you need to index into it.

This should work.
`SELECT JSON_VALUE(@json,'$.test[0].sId');`

Comment: excellent thanks, I look around using the index part but I've been putting it on the wrong area.

Comment: Could you mark as the correct answer if this helped you please :)